# Combining duplicate column headers in a CSV using python

Tags: python, csv

Here is the general idea of my macro I want to perform: A big csv file with column B header "Drug Name" and their respective "Adverse Effects" column D. Currently, I have drugs listed in column B with all its adverse effects listed in column D.  However, I am trying to sort the drugs by adverse effects instead. Many drugs have similar adverse effects but some have unique ones.  I am trying to store all unique values in column D and pair them with their corresponding drug in column B, making this into a new table "drugResults".

Here is an example of my table: [image: Table]
Here is an example of my desired output [image: Desired output]

This is my attempt at the code, it doesn't work properly and I am a n00b at coding python (still trying to learn tho!)

```
import csv

unique_adverse_effects = {}

# Open the CSV file and read the rows
with open('AntiDepressants.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

    # Iterate through each row
    for row in reader:
        # Get the drug name and adverse effects from the current row
        drug_name = row['Drug Name']
        adverse_effects = row['Adverse Effects'].lower()

        # Split the adverse effects string into individual effects
        effects_list = adverse_effects.split('\n')

        # Iterate through each effect and add it to the dictionary
        for effect in effects_list:
            effect = effect.strip().lstrip('- ')
            if effect not in unique_adverse_effects:
                unique_adverse_effects[effect] = [drug_name]
            elif drug_name not in unique_adverse_effects[effect]:
                unique_adverse_effects[effect].append(drug_name)

# Create a new CSV file to store the results
with open('results.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:

    # Write the header row
    writer.writeheader()

    # Write the data rows
    for effect, drugs in unique_adverse_effects.items():
        row_dict = {}
        row_dict[effect.title()] = '\n'.join(drugs)
        writer.writerow(row_dict)
```

Comment: What you have shown is a spreadsheet image. But to understand exactly how the input csv is formatted, we have to see its content **as text**. A csv file **is** a text file, and Excel is among the worst tools to process it... (more exactly it is only a correct tool after you know the exact text content)

Comment: Hm I see, its originally saved as an excel file, but I thought making it into a CSV file would make it easier to work with on python

Comment: You mention "it doesn't work properly". What is it doing? As Serge pointed out, we can't try it without a real file sample.

One weird thing I can see is the "effect.title()", there likely is no such method.

Comment: Im sure alot of the code doesn't make sense or is completely wrong, I'm not that experienced in python except for starting codeacademy a few months ago.  Here is the file I uploaded to my google drive https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gyq4_CZqagqua0St3JER_uG26Zpcpxfk/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106503907993155364372&rtpof=true&sd=true